# activity main MAIN and LAUNCHER is not fired first

Tags: android

I have a launcher activity followed by loginActivity. But everytime I start my APP my loginActivity is fired up first rather than my launcherActivity.
The xml for manifest.xml is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kryptapps.konel.dchat2" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LauncherActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GroupListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_group_list" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

java file is like :

```
public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);
        loadPersonalDatas();

        Thread time = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(20000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        time.start();
    }
    void loadPersonalDatas(){
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

the login activity is like usual log in page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `LauncherActivity` is getting fired, but just for `500` milliseconds.

Whats happening is the wait for `20000` milliseconds and the execution of `loadPersonalDatas()` is carried out simultaneously.

But after `500` milliseconds, the activity changes and `sleep(20000)` is interrupted.

For the `LoginActivity` to launch after `20000` milliseconds, you should start the `LoginActivity` after the `sleep(20000)` in the `run()` method.

```
public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);


        Thread time = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(20000);
                    loadPersonalDatas();             //start activity here
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        time.start();
    }
    void loadPersonalDatas(){
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Now, the `LoginActivity` will start after `20500` milliseconds.

Comment: thanks a lot! i have solved it with a different approach by using intent finally block in try catch block!! But thanks a lot for your help too!!